# Find coefficients of a functional determinant.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, determinant

Let us consider the functional determinant
\begin{gather*}
\Delta=\begin{vmatrix} P_{11}(x,y) & P_{12}(x,y) &P_{13}(x,y)\\
 P_{21}(x,y) & P_{22}(x,y) &P_{23}(x,y)\\
 P_{31}(x,y) & P_{32}(x,y) &P_{33}(x,y)
\end{vmatrix},
\end{gather*}
where $P_{i,j}(x,y)$ are two variable  homogeneous polynomials of some degrees.

After expansion we get a polynomial
$$
\Delta=a_{0,0}+a_{1,0} x+a_{0,1}y+a_{1,1} xy+\cdots+
$$

**Question.** Is there a good close expression for the coefficients $a_{i,j}$?

Of cource,  I can use differentiation
$$
a_{i,j}=\frac{1}{i! j!}\frac{\partial^{i+j} \Delta}{\partial x^i \partial y^j }\Big|_{x=0,y=0}
$$
but this way gives very cumbersome expression.
I hope that there is a simple close solution.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are the $P_{i,j}$ homogeneous ? What are their degrees ?

Comment: Yes, they are homogeneous of arbitrary degrees. I will add it to the  question

Comment: The fact that they are homogeneous could have been used but as they haven't a common degree, I am pessimistic about a simple answer.

Comment: Well, what about simple answer in  the case if they are complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials?

Comment: What do you mean by "complete" ?

Comment: https://handwiki.org/wiki/Complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomial

Comment: Ah, sorry ! I hadn't paid attention to the adjective **symmetric**. Sorry, I haven't any good idea.

Comment: Thank you, anyway